# How many pions can be accomodated in an orbital?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, subatomic, pions

electrons have a spin of 1/2 and 2 electrons are accomodated in an orbital
pions have a spin of 0 so how many pions can be accomodated in an orbital?

i thought that since no two electrons (or pions) can have the same four quantum numbers only one pion should be accomodated in one orbital

Answer (score 0):

Based on particle spin alone there is no restriction on the number pions in the same orbital. Pions are bosons and many pion-states are symmetric under exchange of identical particles. Electrons are fermions and many electron states are anti-symmetric under particle exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about exotic atoms, in your case, pionic atoms.

In this case, the electrons around the nucleus (or in your case a proton) are replaced by pions.

Pions are composite particles, consisting of quark and antiquark. Pions show bosonic characteristics, which means that they do not obey the Pauli exclusion principle.

Now based on this, you would think that you can have as many pions at the same energy level as per QM around the proton as many you want.

In reality, this is not true, because:

1. pions, consisting of quarks and antiquarks, still obey the Heisenberg uncertainty principle
2. pionic atoms have much smaller orbitals then regular atoms, thus the pions are existing around the nucleus much closer to it
3. in pionic atoms, it is not only the EM force that plays a role in keeping the electrons (in this case pions) close to the nucleus, but rather the strong force
4. the closer the pions to the nucleus, the stronger the strong force, and the more chance for the nucleus to pull in the pions into it, but the closer they get, the more the Heisenberg uncertainty principle keeps them from existing too close to the nucleus

Please see here:

https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01674426/document